# Backbone template not changing

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a view with an event.

```
events: {
    'click button.add-prediction': 'addPrediction'
},
addPrediction: function(event) {
    var currentPredictions = this.model.get('count');
    this.model.set('count', currentPredictions + 1);

    this.$el.find('.add-prediction').html('predicted').addClass('selected');
},
```

Doing this:

```
this.$el.find('.add-prediction').html('predicted').addClass('selected');
```

doesn't seem the proper way, but when I do,

```
$(event.target).html('predicted').addClass('selected');
```

The DOM is not updated, why? What m I doing wrong?

Here is the complete view.

```
Event.Views.PredictionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: 'div',
className: 'stats',
events: {
    'click button.add-prediction': 'addPrediction',
    'click button.add-prediction.selected': 'removePrediction'
},
initialize: function() {
    this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
},
removePrediction: function() {
    var currentPredictions = this.model.get('count');
    this.model.set('count', currentPredictions - 2);

    this.$el.find('.add-prediction').html('Predict').removeClass('selected');
    this.$el.removeClass('selected');
    this.$el.parent().find('.add-prediction').removeAttr('disabled');
},
addPrediction: function() {
    var currentPredictions = this.model.get('count');
    this.model.set('count', currentPredictions + 1);

    this.$el.find('.add-prediction').html('Remove prediction').addClass('selected');
    this.$el.addClass('selected');
    this.$el.parent().find('.add-prediction:not(.selected)').attr('disabled', 'true');

},
setTemplate: function() {
    var that = this;
    $.get('templates/singleEvent/team-details.html', function(data) {
        that.template = _.template(data);
        that.render();
    }, 'html');
    return this;
},
render: function() {
    var eventTemplate = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
    $(this.el).html(eventTemplate);
    return this;
}
```

});

Unfortunately I cant make a jsFid, because its too complex and to make it work would take a long time.
Thank you.

Comment: Your button possibly has an img or other element inside it, and the event is being fired on that. This is what event.target will refer to, instead of the button element as you expect.

Comment: No the event.target refers to the button `0: button.btn.btn-quarter.btn-good.add-prediction`

Comment: Can you provide more details? Perhaps even a minimal but functional demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I can try, but its going to be hard, its a very long project :/

Comment: How your render function looks like?

Comment: I would `console.log($(event.target));` in addPrediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.target don't refer button.

event.target[0] refers button.

try to

```
$(event.target[0]).html('predicted').addClass('selected');
```

or

```
event.target.html('predicted').addClass('selected');
```